# Strike through a code part within a code block at Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting

How can I strike through a code part (within code block) at Stack Overflow? Is that possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```html
<!-- language: lang-default -->

<pre><code>System.Out.Println("<s>hello</s> world");
</code></pre>
```

Which turns into:

```
System.Out.Println("hello world");
```

You can put any valid markdown there, including `<b>bold</b>`, `<i>italics</i>` and even links.  You do need to remember to include the `<code>` tags inside `<pre>` for syntax highlighting to work.  The [`language:` comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) before the code block, however, is only needed here on Meta, or if you want to override the automatic choice of which highlighting rules to apply.

Comment: `<b>` and `<i>` also work within the code tag. Care is needed in combination with the `<pre>` tag to avoid stray gray space around the code block.

Comment: @MichaelT thanks, I never used it myself to be honest, just saw it mentioned here from time to time.

Comment: I've used it on *rare* occasions ([example](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/88138/22048)) when I want to be able to highlight a specific block of code and need to get into the html side rendering rather than markdown rendering... and that causes all sorts of fun with `&lt;` rather than `<` and future additional overhead in editing (if someone adds a `<` it breaks everything and they don't know why).

Comment: Good thing to note is that no syntax highlighting when using the `<pre>` tag.

Comment: @Zizouz212 good point, added to the answer. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Zizouz212: Actually, syntax highlighting *does* work, as long as you remember to use `<pre><code>` instead of just `<pre>`; see edit above.