# Why **strong text** does not apply if you use Code Sample?

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting

Here is an example for the issue :

**strong text** works fine here but if you put it in `Code Sample` like:

```
String **varNameInStrongText** = "just try to highlight my var or in comment"
```

It's better that the parser works even if it's a code, i am right ?? or there is a reason behind this choice?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269564/strike-through-a-code-part-within-a-code-block-at-stack-overflow

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `*` can be an operator too. Or what about this:

```
string someVariable = "aa**bb**cc";
```

You don't want that to be formatted as "aa**bb**cc". While highlighting in code seems useful to me, it isn't possible now due to this limitation. I would suggest to use comment style pointers, like this:

```
string someVariable = "aa**bb**cc";  // <-- see here
```

Comment: But i thin the parser can make a difference between `*` and `**` ??

Comment: It can, but `*` is italic, so you have this issue pretty soon.

Comment: Also `**` is an operator too, in Python at least.

Answer (score 11):

The trick is to not use mark down rendering for the code block.  This is not the standard and can certainly confuse people.

```
StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder(""+value1);
String sb2 = ""+value1;
sb1.reverse();
if(sb2.equals(sb1.toString()) && value < value1) {
    value = value1;
}
```

is produced by:

```
<pre><code><b>StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder(""+value1);</b>
<b>String sb2 = ""+value1;</b>
sb1.reverse();
if(sb2.equals(sb1.toString()) && value &lt; value1) {
    value = value1;
}</code></pre>
```

Note the use of the `<b>` tag in the `<code>` block and that `<` needs to be converted to `&lt;`, but it works.

Remember that the code block in markdown is for simple rendering of code. If you want to use html to render the code block instead, you need to use all html and that adds a significant additional burden for people editing the code in the future.  Using markdown indent is the right thing for 99% of the cases.